# Query to concatenate rows into string works in Select Statement, but not in Table Valued Function. What am I missing?

Tags: sql-server, xml, function, concatenation, user-defined-functions

I have a query that will concatenate multiple rows into a delimited list. I am trying to create a table-valued function to make this more repeatable and easier to use, but it doesn't work when using this in a function.

**Here is some test data I am using to build this out:**

```
create table #test (id int not null, val varchar(max))
insert into #test values(1, 'a')
insert into #test values(1, 'b')
insert into #test values(1, 'c')
insert into #test values(2, 'd')
insert into #test values(2, 'e')
insert into #test values(2, 'f')
insert into #test values(3, 'g')
insert into #test values(3, 'h')
insert into #test values(3, 'i')
```

**Code to concatenate rows into list by ID group:**

```
SELECT  distinct
id
--,@values as values
,  STUFF((
    SELECT ', ' + val
    FROM 
        (select t.id, val from #test t ) A
     WHERE a.id = b.id
    FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE 
     /* Use .value to uncomment XML entities e.g. &gt; &lt; etc*/
    ).value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
  ,1,2,'') as list
FROM    
(select t.id, val from #test t)  B
GROUP BY id, val
```

**When I run the following code by itself, here is the before and after result as expected:**

```
Before:                 After:

id  val             id   list
1    a              1    a, b, c
1    b              2    d, e, f
1    c              3    g, h, i
2    d  
2    e  
2    f  
3    g  
3    h  
3    i
```

I have tried several ways to create a TVF with this same code, however I am not getting the expected results.

**Code used to create function:**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[LIST_AGG] 
(   
    @id int,
    @val nvarchar(max) 
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
SELECT  
id
,val
,STUFF((
    SELECT ', ' + val
    FROM 
        (select @id id , @val val) A
     WHERE a.id = b.id
    FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE 
     /* Use .value to uncomment XML entities e.g. &gt; &lt; etc*/
    ).value('.','NVARCHAR(255)') ,1,2,'') as list
FROM    
(select @id id , @val val) B

GROUP BY id, val
)
```

**Code used to call function**

```
select 
t.id
, t.val
, S.list 
from #test t
cross apply dbo.list_AGG(t.id,t.val) as s
```

**And here is the unexpected result when calling the function:**

```
id  val list
1   a   a
1   b   b
1   c   c
2   d   d
2   e   e
2   f   f
3   g   g
3   h   h
3   i   i
```

The 'list' column should be concatenated. I have tried several different ways of accomplishing this to no avail.

Comment: It's not the same code. What's the purpose of the `@val` parameter, what else would you expect to get after filtering by it?

Comment: i don't see you use the `TABLE VALUE PARAMETER` at all

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is build a list of values for each ID, but your function takes in both the ID and the VAL so there is nothing to concatenate.  When you wrote the query out you used the `#test` table to search for all of the VALs for each ID, that is not in your function.

So try this -- I changed the `#test` table to a regular table as functions cannot use temp tables.  If you are looking to do this generically for different tables then you will have to do it another way:

```
CREATE FUNCTION LIST_AGG 
(   
    @id int 
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
    SELECT  
        id,
        STUFF((
            SELECT ', ' + val
            FROM 
                (SELECT id, val FROM test t) A
            WHERE a.id = b.id
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE 
            /* Use .value to uncomment XML entities e.g. &gt; &lt; etc */
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(255)'), 1, 2, '') AS list
    FROM    
        (SELECT @id id) B
    GROUP BY id
)

SELECT DISTINCT t1.id, t2.list
FROM Test t1
CROSS APPLY list_agg(t1.id) t2
```